# Create ImageView and TextView in HorizontalScrollView

Tags: java, android, textview, imageview, scrollview

I want to create a TextView over an ImageView in my Android-App. I know I need a RelativeLayout for this, but I don't know how to create this in my main.java (NOT in XML). 
It should be dynamic, so I want to create a for-loop which creates many ImageViews with a TextView over it in a HorizontalScrollView.

This is my approach

```
LinearLayout sv = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.LinearLayout1);


    for (int i=1 ; i<=3; i++){

        String uri = "drawable/test"; //only one picture several times
        int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());

        ImageView iv = new ImageView (this);
        iv.setBackgroundResource (imageResource);
        sv.addView(iv);
    }
```

This only add ImageViews to my HorizontalScrollView (LinearLayout is located in the HorizontalScrollView), but now I also want to add TextViews over my ImageViews. I tried lot of things but nothing works.. I despair.

Hopefully someone can help me

PS: Sorry for my spelling mistakes, I'm from Germany

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know it to design in xml, create a XML and inflate it.

Below is the code that explains, How to use it.

**Code Snippet**

```
//Parent View
LinearLayout sv = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.LinearLayout1); 

//infalter service
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

//Loop to create all the child views
for (int i=0; i<=3; i++) {

//Refrence your layout xml here
LinearLayout childView= inflater. inflates (R. layout. your_xml, null);

//Get refrence to your button and imageview using childView

//add child view 
sv.addView(childView);
}
//add sv to horizontal scroll view
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude try custom views. Create one XML file and create one basic layout . And then inflate that view as many time as u want don't do with for loop. I thnk u r new in android.

http://androidexample.com/Dynamically_Create_View_Elements__-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=115&aaid=137